# Android "External" folder functionality?

Tags: android, android-source

I find *External* folder in Android sources which if I am not wrong is designed to have U-HAL (User Space Hardware Abstraction Layer) so OEM's can write propriety driver which need not be exposed to outer world under GPL license.

As Android evolved I find more and more folders getting included into *External* folder may be Google is adding more support with each version of Android such as freetype,Yaffs2.

I would like to know how to use external folder logic into Apps? Is that these are generated as Shared Libraries(.so) which in turn apps uses for functionality?

I am not sure how this entire logic which is *propriety* can be embedded in *External* folder and how this communicates with lower layers (may be sysfs)? Is there any blog or documents which describes *External* folder usage , functionality and  HowTo?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Which folder exactly?  I suspect you are not looking at something in the *kernel* sources, but rather the folder in the userspace android sources which contains externally-developed projects adapted for use on android.  None of that functionality is officially available for use by applications except for the portion documented in SDK & NDK apis - some of the undocumented portions may be blocked for permission issues, other may actually work but are subject to change in future releases, which could break apps which depend on such "unstable" apis.

Comment: Sorry Chris, I was referring to **Hardware** folder in Android sources (**AOSP** ), do kindly let me know if you have any information on abstracting driver functionality in Android sources rather than in Kernel.

Comment: You can refer this Android Source Code Description on eLinux http://elinux.org/Android_Source_Code_Description

Answer (score 5):

The *external* folder is not primarily intended for user space hardware abstractions. External refers to external open source libraries. That means libraries that the Android platform depend upon but that are not primarily developed and maintained by the Android open source project. Typical examples are webkit for the browser, FreeType for fonts, SqlLite for databases and so on. As more features are added to Android, more of these libraries are included in external.

If you are looking for a place to put user space hardware drivers the *hardware* folder holds some of these. This is also where the source for the Android hardware abstraction layer (HAL) resides. The *device* folder also contain some hardware specific source for some devices and could be a suitable place to add additional code like this.

For more info on the general layout of the folders in the AOSP see my answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046572/how-to-understand-the-directory-structure-of-android-root-tree)

Comment: Great! Yes, I was referring to **Hardware** folder you have mentioned. It is quite interesting area of my learning to know how exactly Android communicates with underlying Linux kernel without bringing in GPL license into picture and hiding propriety code from public domain. Can you please provide more information regarding **Hardware** folder and a sample app which demonstrates this functionality if in any case documented in a blog or from your experience?

Comment: I see  External folder has implementation for ALSA , YAFFS2 etc, does these files represent GPL license? if so how can we get this into android ?