# why there are so many git projects related to framework in android source?

Tags: android, android-source, android-framework

[image]

you can get this list with link https://android.googlesource.com/?format=HTML

so what is the relation between these projects?

**Edit 1**:

according to [How to understand the directory structure of android root tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046572/how-to-understand-the-directory-structure-of-android-root-tree), we know

> Frameworks - this folder is essential to Android since it contains the sources for the framework. Here you will find the implementation of key services such as the System Server with the Package- and Activity managers. A lot of the mapping between the java application APIs and the native libraries is also done here.

but it is still untold what mff , ml and etc. is, maybe they have something to do with JNI, but what it is exactly? is there any document to tell this details?

Answer (score 1):

The entire [AOSP source](http://source.android.com) consists of a bunch of **git** repositories grouped together and managed using the **repo** tool. All are independent modules in the sense that each has its own repository. Each of them is fetched and stored in a relative ordered fashion. This is managed by **repo** which is a tool built on top of **git**. This is your android source directory after a `repo sync` on your system.

More on **[git, repo & AOSP](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html)**.

---

**Update (to edit1 in question) :**

Just have some patience and check the git logs. For example, **[`git log` of frameworks/ml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ml/+/6b4eebc73439cbc3ddfb547444a341d1f9be7996)** tells me that it is something to do with machine learning and is based on the google-mca project(whatever that is).

With the directory structure changing very frequently and individual projects going in and out of AOSP fairly frequently, it would be hard to find a up-to-date description of the AOSP tree from the top-level. Rather understand that it is just a group of individual projects clubbed together (to work in a nice and orderly manner) and refer to the individual documentation (git log, code, parent-project) of each.

Comment: i want to know the description for these framework related projects, how to do this?

Comment: One way of obtaining descriptive info about the projects would be running `git log` and `git show <commit-id>` from the directory of the project you are interested in. Is that good enough?...

Comment: better there are some documents which are telling the details:)

Comment: ...a decent overview is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046572/how-to-understand-the-directory-structure-of-android-root-tree

Comment: it is still untold what mff , ml and etc. is, maybe they have something to do with JNI, but what it is exactly? is there any document to tell this details? see edit 1:)

Comment: Updated answer in response to the above.