# Is there any documentation available for Android os source code

Tags: android

I want to understand the complete structure of Android OS source code. I have a copy of source code for Gingerbread and want to go through it fully.

Is there any documentation or help available to understand Android OS source tree structure?

Comment: i don't think there is a "complete" documentation of its flow. there are some available in the internet but parts by parts only. and, there are some comments in the source codes.

Comment: actually i want to understand & modify some part of the code & want to see that whether it reflects in final output(emulator/device). So first i need to understand the complete binding & dependencies between different packages.So just comments in code may not help. But anyways thanks for response..

Comment: Some explanation on the folders in Android Source Code

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046572/how-to-understand-the-directory-structure-of-android-root-tree

Comment: yaah.. thanks for link.. it gives overall view of tree structure..it may help in atleast understaning different part of projects

Comment: by the way, do you have a specific functionality that you want to study?

Comment: For time being i m not concentrating on any functionality.. just want to get overall understanding of android source code so can make changes as per requirement.But future target is to communicate with the external hardware.. so need to understand the communication protocol for android os..

Answer (score 1):

Here is some explanation on the folders in Android Source Code to help you get started.

[How to understand the directory structure of android root tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046572/how-to-understand-the-directory-structure-of-android-root-tree)

Answer (score 0):

Source code is documented a little inside source code in comments. There is no official documentation available.

Comment: I believe you meant to say There is **no** official documentation available.