# Description about each project in Android Open Source Project

Tags: android-source

In Android Open Source Project(AOSP) there exists near 500 projects .
I want description about each project and what theirs role are .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is short version of what you will find when you download the Android source.

- Bionic - the C-runtime for Android. Note that Android is not using
  glibc like most Linux distributions. Instead the c-library is called
  bionic and is based mostly on BSD-derived sources. In this folder you
  will find the source for the c-library, math and other core runtime
  libraries.
- Bootable - boot and startup related code. Some of it is legacy, the
  fastboot protocol info could be interesting since it is
  implemented by boot loaders in a number of devices such as the Nexus 
  ones.
- Build - the build system implementation including all the core make
  file templates. An important file here is the envsetup.sh script 
  that will help you a lot when working with the platform source.
  Running this script in a shell will enable commands to setup 
  environment variables, build specific modules and grep in source code
  files.
- Cts - the compatability tests. The test suite to ensure that a build
  complies with the Android specification.
- Dalvik - the source code for the implementation of the Dalvik Virtual
  Machine
- Development - projects related to development such as the source code
  for the sdk and ndk tools. Normally not a folder you touch when 
  working with the platform for a target.
- Device - product specific code for different devices. This is the
  place to find hardware modules for the different Nexus devices, build
  configurations and more.
- External - contains source code for all external open source projects
  such as SQLite, Freetype and webkit.
- Frameworks - this folder is essential to Android since it contains
  the sources for the framework. Here you will find the implementation of key services such as the System Server with the Package and Activity managers. A lot of the mapping between the java application APIs and the native libraries is also done here.
- Hardware - hardware related source code such as the Android hardware
  abstraction layer specification and implementation. This    folder
  also contains the reference radio interface layer (to    communicate
  with the modem side) implementation.
        libcore - Apache Harmony.
        libnativehelper - Helper functions for use with JNI.
        (Kernel) - not part of the default source download but you can get access to this code either by downloading it manually or by adding the repository to the repo tool. Contains the sources for the 
  Android version of the Linux kernel.
- Out - the build output will be placed here after you run make. The
  folder structure is out/target/product/. In the default build for the emulator the output will be placed in out/target/product/generic.
  This is where you will find the images used by the emulator to start 
  (or to be downloaded and flashed to a device if you are building for 
  a hardware target).
- Packages - contains the source code for the default applications such
  as contacts, calendar, browser.
- Prebuilt - contains files that are distributed in binary form for
  convenience. Examples include the cross compilations toolchains for different development machines.
- System - source code files for the core Android system. That is the
  minimal Linux system that is started before the Dalvik VM and any java based services are enabled. This includes the source code for the init process and the default init.rc script that provide the dynamic configuration of the platform
- tools - Various IDE tools.

Beyond the above you also have the hidden .repo directory that contains the source for the repo utility. It also holds the manifest specifying what git repositories you want to track for this Android source project. If you have your own additions you could automatically track them by adding a local manifest here.

For modifications of the platform framework there are some instructions available in the device/sample folder of the source code tree. That will show you how to add APIs to Android without having to modify the core framework.

**References:**

[How to understand the directory structure of android root tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046572/how-to-understand-the-directory-structure-of-android-root-tree)

[Master-android](http://elinux.org/Master-android)